# Call a command in the VS developer command prompt programmatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, subprocess, popen

**Introduction**

I am trying to call a command (`'nmake'`) that needs to be run from inside the VS Developer Command Prompt using `Subprocess.Popen` in python.

Setting the path for it won't work for my case.

I tried reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) and it didn't seem like there is a way to use something other than the default CMD.exe.

**My code**

```py
import subprocess

command = ['nmake']
with subprocess.Popen(["nmake"],
                      executable=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsMSBuildCmd.bat",
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                      universal_newlines=True) as process:
    print(process.stdout.readlines())
    print(process.stderr.readlines())
```

**Exception**

It currently throws

`'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

so it's not actually using the executable provided there.

**Notes**

System used : Windows 10, python3.8

Comment: The VS developer prompt _is_ CMD.exe. However, CMD is running that batch file from the Visual Studio install to set the path right.  You may want to test `...\VsMSBuildCmd.bat & nmake` but I don't know for certain if the results of `VsMSBuildCmd.bat` happens before `nmake` is started. Logically, it should.

Comment: that sadly doesn't work `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\VsMSBuildCmd.bat" & nmake` returns nmake is not recognized and then runs the bat I think.

Comment: You may want to make your own wrapper batch file then. That allows you to put those two commands on separate lines, and CMD only needs to call the wrapper.

Comment: What do you mean by **Setting the path for it won't work for my case.** Can you modify the path using sys.path? Do you know the location of nmake.exe? Mostly in bin dir of C compiler.

Comment: I do know the path of nmake.exe but that itself isn't enough because it depends on a lot of other libraries that the .bat file adds to the path temporarily.

Comment: Just a random guess : try passing nmake as argument  `--nmake` to bat file

Comment: Did you try `NMAKE.EXE`?

Comment: passing --nmake returns a `[ERROR:parse_cmd.bat] Invalid command line argument: 'nmake'. Argument will be ignored` . also trying nmake.exe returns the same result. I think windows adds the exe itself when calling executables

Answer (score 2):

I FINALLY(!!) managed to get this kind of thing done, with cmake.
I've been struggling with this thing for the whole day, nothing on google was able to solve this in such a concise manner.

I use the VS Developer Command Prompt to run cmake with -GNinja for my CMake project in Windows, like "cmake  -GNinja" but I needed to use python to run this automatically, here's how:

For running without Python, just in a regular cmd.exe / powershell, what you should do is run this, notice the "&" to chain the commands:

C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft Visual Studio"\2019\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat "&" cmake ..\src -GNinja

You can put this in a .bat file to run that file from some script, or do something like this in Python:

```
os.chdir("C:\\git\\project\\build") # Changing to the build dir next to the project's src dir to build it with cmake.

os.system('C:\\"Program Files (x86)"\\"Microsoft Visual Studio"\\2019\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat' + "&" + 'cmake ..\\src -GNinja')  # Running cmake inside VS Developer CMD Prompt to get all the necessary libs and compilers automatically.
```

Example output from pycharm:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" C:/git/automation/123.py
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.10.3
** Copyright (c) 2021 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30038.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30038.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30037/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30037/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/git/project/build

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Afterwards if you want to use the ninja "make" to build some targets it's the same thing:

```
os.system('C:\\"Program Files (x86)"\\"Microsoft Visual Studio"\\2019\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat' + "&" + 'ninja <targetName>')
```

I assume that for your nmake it will be something similar to this:

```
os.system('C:\\"Program Files (x86)"\\"Microsoft Visual Studio"\\2019\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat' + "&" + 'nmake')
```

Hope it solves your problem as it has for me.

Comment: Thanks for this. To other readers: don't miss the part about the `&`!!

Answer (score 1):

This probably happens in the cases in handling quotes in path filename. Few things which you can try:

1. In `popen` argument add `shell=True` this causes subprocess to spawn an intermediate shell process, and tell it to run the command
2. Use `executable = [r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsMSBuildCmd.bat"]`

Comment: executable expects a string not a list of strings. 
Also, passing shell=True didn't change anything sadly. I've already tried before too but with no luck.